# Build nuget package in Release mode?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013, nuget, windows-phone-8.1

I've updated my Windows Phone app from 8 to 8.1. Everything works, no problems testing it in either debug or release modes.

The issue is when I try to certify the app for the Store. I get the following notice about my Nuget package `ImageTools`:

```
The binary ICSharpCode.SharpZLib.Phone.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary ImageTools.Controls.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary ImageTools.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary ImageTools.Filtering.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary ImageTools.IO.Png.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary ImageTools.Utils.dll is built in debug mode.
```

I didn't have this problem in WP8. Perhaps something went wrong in the project upgrade? I've tried reinstalling the nuget package as well as manually placing the DLLs into the project.

I don't know how to build `ImageTools` in release mode. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Apps (And Silverlight 8.1 Apps) have a different certification requirement. You cannot publish assemblies built in debug mode.

You'll need to contact the NuGet authors of ICSharpCode and ImageTools and have them provide you with a version built in release mode.

Comment: To anyone else facing the same problem: There's an issue on CodePlex, please vote. https://imagetools.codeplex.com/workitem/13006

Comment: You can download these assemblies without the [Debuggable] attribute here: https://github.com/brianhama/ImageTools-WP81

Answer (score 1):

I modified the IL of the assemblies and removed the [Debuggable] attribute from them.  The Windows Phone Store now allows the submission.  You can download the patched assemblies here: https://github.com/brianhama/ImageTools-WP81